# Packaging a custom DirectX redistributable installer

Tags: directx, windows-installer, direct3d9

Following MS' [advice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) we have stripped most files from the DX installer contents for our D3D9 application, getting it down to 5Mb in total.
But now I;d like to package these files into a single installer, like the redistributable installers MS themselves provide... so it can be run as part of our application install process, with /silent switch, without manually having to unpackage the files and delete them.
Is there a simple, standard way to do this so that the packaged DXSetup.exe is run?

Or is all this too complex and we should just unpack the files, run DXSetup.exe and then delete the files after installation?

Answer (score -1):

Its better to use the installers that MS provide, usually is what Apps do, if the problem is space you could always use web installer its 300kb but will require the user to have an internet connection.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2da43d38-db71-4c1b-bc6a-9b6652cd92a3&displaylang=en

On the other and if you're using DirectX SDK

there is a folder "redist"
and in it there are setup's of DX,
you can distribute them with your app,
and your Setup has to call the dxsetup.exe

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I need to be able to install silently, webinstaller downloads ALL DX components also and I only need D3DX.